# How to make SpinBox loose focus when clicking on buttons of another SpinBox in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I'm having a specific problem where i click on the text on the middle of a `SpinBox` and it gets focus but after that i go to another `SpinBox`and i click on the `-` or `+`, when i do that i want to get the focus out of the last `SpinBox` to the new one, for that value to get assumed.

As an example, lets suppose i click on the top SpinBox:
[image]

Now i click on the `+`button on the bottom `SpinBox`, doing that i want to get the focus on this bottom `SpinBox`

[image]

I provide the code of `main.qml`below:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    title: "Stack"
    visible: true
    height: 200
    width: 400
    ListModel {
        id: libraryModel
        ListElement {
            text: "A Masterpiece"
        }
        ListElement {
            text: "Brilliance"
        }
        ListElement {
            text: "Outstanding"
        }
    }

    Item {
        id: page
        anchors.fill: parent
        width:parent.width
        height: parent.height
        ScrollView {
            id:scrollView
            anchors.fill:parent
            style: ScrollViewStyle{
                handle: Rectangle {
                    implicitWidth: 30
                    color:  "black"
                }
                scrollToClickedPosition: true
                transientScrollBars:true
            }
            function scrollToY(y) {
                scrollView.contentItem.contentY = y;
            }
            Column{
                width:parent.width
                spacing:10
                TextField {
                    id:textField
                    implicitHeight: 30
                    font.bold: true
                    onFocusChanged: if(focus) { scrollView.scrollToY(y); }
                }
                ComboBox {
                    id:comboBox
                    anchors.topMargin: 10
                    textRole: "text"
                    model: libraryModel
                    onFocusChanged: if(focus) { scrollView.scrollToY(y); }
                }
                SpinBox {
                    width: 100
                    height: 30
                    editable: true
                }
                SpinBox {
                    width: 100
                    height: 30
                    editable: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`focusPolicy`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html#focusPolicy-prop):

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    height: 200
    width: 400
    visible: true

    Column{
        spacing: 10

        SpinBox {
            width: 100
            height: 30
            editable: true
        }
        SpinBox {
            width: 100
            height: 30
            editable: true
            focusPolicy: Qt.ClickFocus // or Qt.StrongFocus
        }
    }
}
```

`Qt.ClickFocus` will give focus to the control when it's clicked, `Qt.TabFocus` for tab, `Qt.WheelFocus` for wheel, `Qt.StrongFocus` for all three.